# Navigation bar with UIImage for title

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I want to customize my app's look by using a logo image as the navigation bar's title, instead of plain text. When I use this code

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
self.navigationItem.titleView = logo;
```

I get the error "UIImage is not convertible to UIView". How can I do this correctly?

Comment: ** let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "App_icons")
        self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView**

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Put it inside an `UIImageView`

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Comment: where in the class declaration are you putting this?

Comment: @JackWu It doesn't work if I add it to `UINavigationController.viewDidLoad` (the class which I implemented for navigation controller), but it works if I added to `ViewController`. But I want to keep this code separated (so inside my class which extends UINavigationController). Is it possible?

Comment: @Ronaldoh1 This is doing exactly the same thing you are in your answer so I don't know how you can say "this doesn't work anymore"

Comment: This works, but you have to use `viewDidLoad` in the view controller that is pushed to the navigation controller, not the navigation controller itself.

Comment: If it didn't work, make sure you set the class of controller to the file you are putting this code in.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I've tried it & it works. However, how do I adjust the logo so that it fits well and not stretch in the whole navigation bar. Or should I just change my logo size.

Comment: @ConsBulaquena possibly a combination of both. There are at least 20 question/answers combos here on stack overflow, in fact check the sidebar and you will find the “related/linked” ————>

Answer (score 64):

I use this. It works in iOS 8

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let image = UIImage(named: "YOURIMAGE")
    navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
}
```

And here is an example how you can do it with CGRect.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 38, height: 38))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: "YOURIMAGE")
    imageView.image = image
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: where in the navigation bar subclass are you putting this?

Comment: @Hossein I cannot remember, it has been a while and do not have the project. Sorry.

Answer (score 35):

For swift 4 and you can adjust imageView size

```
 let logoContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 270, height: 30))

 let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 270, height: 30))
 imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
 let image = UIImage(named: "your_image")
 imageView.image = image
 logoContainer.addSubview(imageView)
 navigationItem.titleView = logoContainer
```

Answer (score 14):

I tried @Jack's answer above, the logo did appear however the image occupied the whole Navigation Bar. I wanted it to fit.

**Swift 4, Xcode 9.2**

1.Assign value to navigation controller, UIImage. Adjust size by dividing frame and Image size.

```
func addNavBarImage() {

        let navController = navigationController!

        let image = UIImage(named: "logo-signIn6.png") //Your logo url here
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

        let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
        let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height

        let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - (image?.size.width)! / 2
        let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - (image?.size.height)! / 2

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }
```

2. Add the function right under `viewDidLoad()`

   ```
       addNavBarImage()
   ```

Note on the image asset. Before uploading, I adjusted the logo with extra margins rather than cropped at the edges.

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Resizing doesn't worked with me, but I fixed it by increasing size of right & left bar item width.

Comment: can you answer on my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521575/title-image-position-changing-when-changing-the-tab-swift

Answer (score 10):

You can use custom UINavigationItem so, you only need to change "Navigation Item" as YourCustomClass on the Main.storyboard.

**In Swift 3**

```
class FixedImageNavigationItem: UINavigationItem {

private let fixedImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "your-header-logo.png")!
private let imageView : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 37.5))

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = fixedImage
    self.titleView = imageView

}

}
```

Answer (score 6):

this worked for me in Sept 2015 - Hope this helps someone out there.

```
// 1
    var nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    // 2 set the style 
    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    // 3
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    // 4
    let image = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
    imageView.image = image
    // 5
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Comment: if this solution doesn't work, try creating a reference to the navigation bar in the UIViewController class.

@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!

Then instead of 
    `navigationItem.titleView = imageView`
do
    `self.navBar.topItem?.titleView = imageView`

It is explained here:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619131/setting-titleview-of-custom-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 6):

Here is a handy function for Swift 4.2, shows an image with title text:-

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Sets the navigation title with text and image
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navTitleWithImageAndText(titleText: "Dean Stanley", imageName: "online")
}

func navTitleWithImageAndText(titleText: String, imageName: String) -> UIView {

    // Creates a new UIView
    let titleView = UIView()

    // Creates a new text label
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = titleText
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.center = titleView.center
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    // Creates the image view
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

    // Maintains the image's aspect ratio:
    let imageAspect = image.image!.size.width / image.image!.size.height

    // Sets the image frame so that it's immediately before the text:
    let imageX = label.frame.origin.x - label.frame.size.height * imageAspect
    let imageY = label.frame.origin.y

    let imageWidth = label.frame.size.height * imageAspect
    let imageHeight = label.frame.size.height

    image.frame = CGRect(x: imageX, y: imageY, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)

    image.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit

    // Adds both the label and image view to the titleView
    titleView.addSubview(label)
    titleView.addSubview(image)

    // Sets the titleView frame to fit within the UINavigation Title
    titleView.sizeToFit()

    return titleView

}
```

Comment: This works great. One question: How can we make sure the image is always circular? How should the corner radius be set? @Gagandeep

Answer (score 4):

I have written this for iOS 10 & iOS 11 and it worked for me:

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    func setupNavigationBar() {
        let titleImageWidth = frame.size.width * 0.32
        let titleImageHeight = frame.size.height * 0.64
        var navigationBarIconimageView = UIImageView()
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationBarIconimageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: titleImageWidth).isActive = true
            navigationBarIconimageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: titleImageHeight).isActive = true
        } else {
            navigationBarIconimageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: titleImageWidth, height: titleImageHeight))
        }
        navigationBarIconimageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        navigationBarIconimageView.image = UIImage(named: "image")
        topItem?.titleView = navigationBarIconimageView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5.1+, Xcode 13+**

Sometimes if your image is in high resolution then, imageView shifts from centre, I would suggest using this method

```
  lazy var navigationTitleImageView = UIImageView()

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            
    self.navigationTitleImageView.image = logo
    self.navigationTitleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    
    self.navigationTitleImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    if let navC = self.navigationController{
        navC.navigationBar.addSubview(self.navigationTitleImageView)
        self.navigationTitleImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navC.navigationBar.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.navigationTitleImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navC.navigationBar.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.navigationTitleImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navC.navigationBar.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
        self.navigationTitleImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navC.navigationBar.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.088).isActive = true
    }
}
```

and viewWillDisappear()

```
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationTitleImageView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

or else just reduce the image size

Comment: what's self.setNavigationBar()?

Comment: Actually, thats is the custom function in witch the following below code was written.. Thanks for pointing out, i will remove it.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you set a text to the `title` property of the `View Controller` or the `navigationItem.title` of this Navigation Controller, that text will be visible behind the image you added here, and we don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd prefer to use autolayout, and want a permanent fixed image in the navigation bar, that doesn't animate in with each screen, this solution works well:

```
class CustomTitleNavigationController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let logo = UIImage(named: "MyHeaderImage")

    let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    navigationBar.addSubview(imageView)

    navigationBar.addConstraint (navigationBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leftAnchor, constant: 0))
    navigationBar.addConstraint (navigationBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.rightAnchor, constant: 0))
    navigationBar.addConstraint (navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor, constant: 0))
    navigationBar.addConstraint (navigationBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically could be done like this.

```
private var imageView: UIView {

    let bannerWidth = navigationBar.frame.size.width * 0.5 // 0.5 its multiplier to get correct image width
    let bannerHeight = navigationBar.frame.size.height

    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)

    let image = UIImage(named: "your_image_name")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

    view.addSubview(imageView)

    return view
}
```

The just change titleView

```
navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Answer (score 1):

let's do try and checkout

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Navbar_bg.png")
navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me in swift 4 (square image 40x40)

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.frame.size.width = 40
imageView.frame.size.height = 40
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
let image = UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME")
imageView.image = image
navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

If you want other measures, try

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 100.5)))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
let image = UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME")
imageView.image = image
navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

I hope it serves you. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: (CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 
    40)))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage (named: "logo") // logo is your NPG asset 
    imageView.image = image
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Comment: Please elaborate what your code does. Code-only answers are considered bad quality in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... try it

```
let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "LogoName")
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = image
navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C** version:

```
//create the space for the image
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 256, 144)];
//bind the image with the ImageView allocated
myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
//add image into imageview
_myNavigationItem.titleView = myImage;
```

Just in case someone (like me) had arrived here looking for the answer in **Objective-C**.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the image view with the proper size and in the center, you should use the following approach:

```
let width = 120 // choose the image width
let height = 20 // choose the image height
let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44)) //44 is the standard size of the top bar
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (view.bounds.width - width)/2, y: (44 - height)/2, width: width, height: height))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //choose other if it makes sense
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "your_image_name")
titleView.addSubview(imageView)
navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "App_icons")
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```