# setting titleView of custom UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, ios8

I have a custom navigation bar that doesn't really do any navigation controlling (app only has one view) its instead used as a header to display the logo against a solid background colour. So I put a navigation bar onto the main view controller and created an outlet so I can reference it in the code. (Using swift by the way).

Right now I'm struggling with setting the logo image in the center of the nav bar. I need to do this with the titleView (instead of setting an entire background image). So far what I've read says to use `self.navigationItem.titleView` in the view controller, but I think that only works when using a UINavigationController. Here is my code so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let logoImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 200, height: 45))
    logoImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
    logoImage.image = logo
    self.navigationItem.titleView = logoImage
}
```

But this doesn't work. How do I get access to the titleView using a custom UINavigationBar like this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to access `UINavigationBar`'s `topItem` attribute.
Then you can set the `topItem`'s `titleView` with a `UIImageView`.

So in your case:

```
self.navBar.topItem?.titleView = logoImage
```

Comment: I used self.navBar.topItem? to get a reference to the first (and only) navigational item which in turn gave me access to the titleView property. Thanks this helped a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I mean't `self.navBar`. I'll fix it.

Comment: What's the difference between topItem and navigationItem? Shouldn't there be one property by which we access stuff in NavigationBar of UINavigationController?

Comment: @PaulBrewczynski use topItem for a `UINavigationBar` not embedded in a `UINavigationController`. Otherwise use navigationItem.