# Set navbar title background color (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit

I am wanting to change the background of the UI Navbar title in iOS. I want the final result to appear like the image below:

[image]

Please let me know if this is possible or if I will have to do a workaround.

[Changing navigation bar color in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687238/changing-navigation-bar-color-in-swift) does not address the background color of the title text for the UINavigationBar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing navigation bar color in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687238/changing-navigation-bar-color-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you need to add a UIView to the navigationBarTitleView. Then add a label or UIImageView to the Uiview and Finaly add that view to the TitleView. So here I've added label to the titleView. Hope that this will gonna help you:-

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let navBarView: UIView = UIView()
    navBarView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0, 21.0)

    let label: UILabel = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90.0, 21.0)
    label.text = "Your Title"
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    navBarView.addSubview(label)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navBarView
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

So here is the output :-

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I could move the created label up some? I have been trying for some time now with no luck.

Comment: Didn't get you .., what do you want to do ?

Comment: I figured it out `navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(CGFloat(-14), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the `titleView` property of `UINavigationBar`. Try something like this

```
    // Create new label that will service as a title view
    let titleView = UILabel()
    /* customize label to heart's content */
    titleView.text = "TITLE HERE"
    // Set your custom background color
    titleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    // Now set this is as the titleView of the navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

If you have a statically managed managed `UINavigationBar` (not a part of UINavigationController). Something like this should work:

```
    navBar.pushNavigationItem(self.navigationItem, animated: NO)
```

Comment: Nothing is showing up when I do this. Should in be in viewDidLoad() ?

Comment: @MattButler where did you put it?

Comment: Do you have your view controller embedded in a UINavigationController? Try to print out `self.navigationController` in viewWillAppear.

Comment: It returned nil. I am just using a navbar inside of a standard UIViewController. The navbar is static

Comment: You need to add this code to the view controller that owns the navigation bar. If you have a static navigation bar then push the navigation item to the navigation bar

Comment: shouldn't I be adding something other than `self.navigationItem`? This is not affecting the titleView when I run

Comment: This link may be of help. When I apply this method the title is then blank http://stackoverflow.com/a/29619429/5527548

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeNavigationController: UINavigationController {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.navigationBar.topItem?.title = NavTitle
    }

}
```

I have referenced `NavTitle`from a constants swift class. I hope this helps!