# How to change the background color of TabBar title string only in swift code

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I'd like to put a background color for just the `title` of TabBar using swift I tried to use `NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor` but it not appears color in the background.

Can anybody help me to change the background color for just the `title` of TabBar?

I need to add yellow color to the background to title in the normal state not selected.

Comment: please share code where you're assigning the title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set navbar title background color (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558042/set-navbar-title-background-color-swift)

Answer (score 1):

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.gray], for: .selected)
```

This works for a single item. If you'd like to change the color for all items in the tab bar, try parsing through them like such

```
for item in self.tabBar.items! {

      item.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .normal)
      item.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.gray], for: .selected)

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ...but I need to know how to change the background color of title not to change the title color ..

Comment: @IosMohammed I just now understand what you want to do. I would suggest creating a custom View for the tab bar title in which you can add a label over a background view. The default title doe snot support the behavior you are expecting. 
Doing this will result in a fully customizable background view, from rounding corners to gradients, you name it.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following code snippet to your viewDidLoad:

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black // your color
```