# iOS Swift Add Image to Navigation Bar in Centre While Keeping Aspect Ratio

Tags: ios, swift

I've been looking for a solution for this for more time than I'd care to admit. I've managed to add a background image, although this then skews the image so it isn't right.

I'm looking for how to add an image to a NavigationBar in the centre? I want to add a centre aligned logo to the top screen.

This particular section of the app is contained within a Navigation Controller which pops up as a modal for Logging In before the user can go any further. Once logged in then the remaining parts of the app will likely be contained within a Tab Bar Controller. Not sure if this makes any difference when trying to add a logo, so mentioning just in case.

The documentation on everything Swift related from Apple is abysmal.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Did you try suggested? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803178/swift-navigation-bar-image-title?rq=1

Comment: Yes I've tried adding that code into the viewDidLoad() and viewDidAppear() sections and no image shows at all.

Comment: Can you show the code you have currently, that shows the distorted image?