# Adding UIImage ignores and resizes UIImageView frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, storyboard, uinavigationitem

I'm currently trying to add an image into the navigation item for one view. In the view's `viewDidLoad()`, a function is called with the following code, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803178/swift-navigation-bar-image-title):

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "Menu_Logo")

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 122, height: 26))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.image = logo

self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Instead of giving me the expected size however, the view ends up looking like this:

[image: UIImageView expanded]
[image: Inspector shows the size grew above the defined frame]

Removing the UIImage from the UIImageView makes the view sized correctly like this:

[image: UIImageView is sized like expected when no UIImage is set]
[image: The expected size of 122/26 is displayed when inspecting the view]

This seems like strange behaviour to me, especially since I did set the content mode to `.scaleAspectFit`. Is there something I am forgetting regarding adding an `UIImageView` as the `navigationItem.titleView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `UINavigationBar`, title view takes its full size, if content is large.

> Resize the image rather than `UIImageView` as following with passing size (122, 26). This will solve your problem.

```
func imageResize(sizeChange: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let hasAlpha = true
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Use scale factor of main screen

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeChange, !hasAlpha, scale)
    self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: sizeChange))

    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    return scaledImage!
}
```

Comment: While this does seem like a bit of a hack-y way around strange behaviour of the system, this definitely works. I wrote the function as an extension to the UIImage class. Thank you!