# How to Use Image as title on large Navigation Bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, titlebar, large-title

I’m trying to set an image as the title on a large navigation bar. So far I can just get it to display the logo in the top centre like it would if it was a standard navigation bar.

I’m trying to replace “All Inboxes” with an image.

[image]

At the moment I’m getting something like this
by using `self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image #i ageLiteral(resourceName: “logo pic”))`
[image]

Note - the title text “settings” does not appear but the logo/image is in that place shown as “The logo” . (I want the image/logo to be lower and to the left as in the first pic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can already place the image in the bar, so now it's just a matter of resizing the view so it fits to your desired position.

Do this by resizing the frame of the `UIImage`, as resizing the `UIImageView` alone doesn't work in the navigation bar (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49813761/4442731)).

**Edit:** After some experimentation, I managed to do what you want. It's a bit hack-y and you might need to figure out the correct size values for yourself, but I managed to achieve this view:

[image: the logo positions at the correct point]

This was done by adding a `UIView` titled "container" as the `titleView`, which then contained a `UIImageView`. While "container" is mostly restricted to the "top" part of the bar, the contained `UIImageView` is able to move freely inside the Navigation Bar now. You can see how this is a bit hack-y:

[image: the logo is right over the usual title text, the container is black]

In this image you can see that the container `UIView` has a black background color. It can't grow past a certain size as the `titleView`. Inspecting the view hierarchy shows you how the logo is positioned:

[image: view hierarchy]

This was achieved through the following code:

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo")

let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 182, height: 132))
container.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

let imageView = UIImageView(frame:  CGRect(x: -132, y: 2, width: 182, height: 132))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = logo

container.addSubview(imageView)

self.navigationItem.titleView = container
```

As I said, this is hack-y and certainly not intended by Apple. This solution might not work in future versions of iOS.

You can also set `width` and `height` of `container` to `0` and experiment from there. It's all about manually finding the right frame values through trial and error.

Comment: Yeah but doesn’t it restrict you to just that area at the top for title images?

Comment: @NolanRanolin I'll experiment with it myself and get back to you. Haven't used the large NavBar yet.

Comment: @NolanRanolin please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks it’s working good so far. The only issue is that the logo disappears if I push to a view with a small title bar and then go back to the view with the large title bar

Comment: @NolanRanolin Where in your code did you call the functions? Sounds like you're calling it in "viewDidLoad". Try moving it to "viewWill/DidAppear".

Comment: I initially had it in viewDidLoad but moving it to ViewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear didn’t make a difference, still getting the same result

Comment: I tried setting it in viewWillDissapear as well so the logo is added to the titleBar of both views but the logo still goes away