# How can a custom control be added to navigation header of a Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to design a custom Table view with a segmented control at the top like the image below . (That's from whatsapp)

[image: nav with segmented control]

Some experiments

- UINavigationBar has a topItem but that's for the title which is still needed
- Creating a vertical stack view with a segmentedcontrol and UITable looks ok, but scroll on the table does not cause the segmentedcontrol to scroll out. And the navigation bar is still above the segmented control.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803178/navigation-bar-with-uiimage-for-title. Just use a UISegmentedControl instead of a UIImageView.

Comment: i tried the example from  ^ but that changes the title itself. the segmented control for this question is above the title and does not replace it. thanks @rmaddy

Comment: They are using a large title navigation bar, and placing the segmented control in the navigation bar's `titleView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation bar with UIImage for title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803178/navigation-bar-with-uiimage-for-title)