# Set UIBarButtonItem with circular Image profile

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

How to set UIBarButton with circular image profile

[image: ar]

```
func loadProfile(){

        let url = URL(string: "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1312461204/sample.jpg")!

let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let img = UIImage(data: data)
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
imageView.image = img?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(barButton, animated: false)
```

Comment: You can place the imageView inside a UIView. It should fix the width issue. You can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47689599/8665577

Comment: It’s for rightBarButton, not for title

Comment: for 40 height ... your corners radius should e 20

Comment: what width you are looking for ?

Comment: I set coroner radius  to 20

Answer (score 1):

Failed to set Constrains thats why its behaviors!

```
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonWidth).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonHeight).isActive = true
```

Fixed Issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried set content mode in your imageView ?

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this, as suggested by kiran, setting the `imageView` frame size is not enough. You should also set the height and width constraints. Otherwise, any animation to the navigation bar will result in the `imageView.image` occupying the whole `navigationBar` width, as seen in the image posted by the OP.

```
func loadProfile(){
    let url = URL(string: "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1312461204/sample.jpg")!

    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let img = UIImage(data: data)
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
    
    // NEW CODE HERE: Setting the constraints
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    
    imageView.image = img?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(barButton, animated: false)
}
```